# Can't pass data to handlebars template

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, templating

I am following the tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zVYH16yogQ&t=58s about rendering data in handlebars template but can't seem to pass the data to the template.

My global.js file:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){



var source = $("#first-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);


var context = {
  title1 : "hello",
  body1 : "body1"
}

var el_html = template(context);

$("#render_here").html(el_html);
$("#render_here_again").html(el_html);


});
```

My view file:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/global.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <button name = "click" id ="click" >click </button>
<div id ="render_here">
  first
</div>

<div id ="render_here_again">
  second
</div>

<script id = "first-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
          <div>
                <h1 style ="color:green">{{title1}}</h1>
                <h2 style ="color:blue">{{body1}}</h2>
        </div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When rendering the page the data from the context variable should be loaded, however it is blank. I can see the object when I log it in the console, and when I console.log(el_html) the script template comes up but without the context. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. Here is the code - the only real change I made was to put the global.js inline and to modernize the version of jQuery:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var source = $("#first-template").html();
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

            var context = {
                title1 : "hello",
                body1 : "body1"
            };

            var el_html = template(context);

            $("#render_here").html(el_html);
            $("#render_here_again").html(el_html);

        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button name = "click" id ="click" >click </button>
<div id ="render_here">
    first
</div>

<div id ="render_here_again">
    second
</div>

<script id = "first-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div>
        <h1 style ="color:green">{{title1}}</h1>
        <h2 style ="color:blue">{{body1}}</h2>
    </div>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, you are using an ancient version of jQuery. I would move to something more recent - at least 2.x. There is no reason to use v1.x anymore.

Comment: for some reason my page is still coming up blank, this is  a long shot but would you know of anything else that might be interfering with it? I'm using node.js mongodb express and handlebars

Comment: So when you run my code in your environment, you get a blank page?

Comment: yeah its completely blank except for the button.. I can't figure it out but I can capture the context if i log it in the console before I render it.. its after I render the page the context seems to get lost somewhere